# Support AVIF in MAMP

Tags: mamp, avif

I'm trying to convert an image to avif using imageavif() using PHP 8.2 on MAMP but it seems lack of avif support. It is the latest version of MAMP (ver 6.8).

This is the PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imageavif()
```

This is the output of gd_info():

```
Array
(
    [GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
    [FreeType Support] => 1
    [FreeType Linkage] => with freetype
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPEG Support] => 1
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] => 
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [WebP Support] => 1
    [BMP Support] => 1
    [AVIF Support] => 
    [TGA Read Support] => 1
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```

It doesn't support AVIF. Is there any way to make it support AVIF on MAMP?